# Chrome extension fails to load with: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'inspectedWindow')

Tags: google-chrome-extension, chrome-extension-manifest-v3

This code belongs to a background script. However, it isn't called during startup. Just the presence of the code leads to: "Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'inspectedWindow')" and the script failing to start. If I comment it out and replace it with a console.log, the console is not logged to and the script starts without issues. It is true that the receiver of the message doesn't exist during startup (it's a content script which won't exist until later) but surely chrome shouldn't care until it's time to send the message.

And how is inspectedWindow involved in any case?

```
        try {
            chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tabId, {type: "ping"}, (response) => {
                // not doing anything with this right now
            });
        } catch (err) {
            console.log("Tab gone?");
        }
```

Changing it to chrome.runtime.sendMessage lets the script load. But, again, the code isn't in the execution path of app startup, so why does chrome care?

Comment: Can you provide a [minimal, complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)? That would be sweet!

Comment: You might be looking at an old error in chrome://extensions UI. Click the trashcan icon or `Clear all` button to remove it. Note that the background script can't use chrome.devtools API. Only the [devtools page/panel](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/devtools) can do it.